# Getting EPSG code from QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem

Tags: coordinate-system, pyqgis, string

I can create a `QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem` from a EPSG ID.

How can I get a string formatted like `EPSG:4326` back from the `QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem`?

```py
>>> p = QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem.fromEpsgId(4326)

>>> p.toProj()
'+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs'

>>> p.userFriendlyIdentifier()
'EPSG:4326 - WGS 84'
```

Do I really have to use `p.userFriendlyIdentifier().split(" ")[0]` or is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the [`userFriendlyIdentifier()`](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsCoordinateReferenceSystem.html#aaa522e1327218a01850174c72a219293) method with the [`ShortString`](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsCoordinateReferenceSystem.html#a6dc6a36cdc8323f8bae26bc94bb9dcc6aa5d6d857c149a9555065dc7450ba91c7) type:

> Returns a user-friendly identifier for the CRS.
>
> Depending on the format of the CRS, this may reflect the CRSes
> registered name, or for CRSes not saved in the database it may reflect
> the underlying WKT or Proj string definition of the CRS.
>
> In most cases, this is the best method to use when showing a friendly
> identifier for the CRS to a user.

Available since QGIS 3.10.3

```py
p = QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem.fromEpsgId(4326)

if p.isValid():
    print(p.userFriendlyIdentifier(type=QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem.ShortString)) #EPSG:4326
```

Also there is [`geographicCrsAuthId()`](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsCoordinateReferenceSystem.html#acfd9eae9ba8c7b80142dc4033991da07) method available:

> Returns auth id of related geographic CRS.

```py
p = QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem.fromEpsgId(4326)

if p.isValid() and p.isGeographic():
    print(p.geographicCrsAuthId()) #EPSG:4326
```

Answer (score 3):

Found a corresponding method [`authid()`](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/master/core/QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem.html#qgis.core.QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem.authid).

```py
>>> p = QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem.fromEpsgId(4326)

>>> p.authid()
'EPSG:4326'
```